# Why does this dropdown form filter work on a native table but not an ODBC linked table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I'm transitioning an Access user app from using native Access tables to using ODBC-linked SQL Server tables.

I have a set of forms that are filtered by a selection from a dropdown (in a stand-alone selection form).  By design, if the user leaves the dropdown blank the form launches unfiltered.

All of this works with the native tables, but when I try it using the linked tables I get an `ODBC--call failed` error

The SQL query Access generated for the query I'm using as the Record Source of the form that is filtered is:

```
SELECT linked.ASSIGNED_CARE_COORDINATOR, [rest of the variables]
WHERE (((linked.ASSIGNED_CARE_COORDINATOR)=[Forms]![frmCoord_Selector]![cmbCoords]))
OR   (((([linked].[ASSIGNED_CARE_COORDINATOR]) 
     Like [Forms]![frmDeadline_Report_Coord_Selector]![cmbCoords]) Is Null));
```

I know the ODBC connection itself is fine; if I remove the code after `OR` the query works with the linked table, but of course doesn't have the show-all-if-null functionality.

Why would this work with a native table but not the linked version of the exact same table?

Comment: Please advise on *query underlying the filter*. Is this query a form recordsource, a drop down field's controlsource, a VBA recordset, or other? Also, it is unclear the logic of `OR` as you seem to combine two expressions: `LIKE` and `IS NULL`. Did you copy this correctly here?

Comment: @Parfait the query is the form record source (added this is question text as well).  I checked the copy, it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `LIKE` in the `OR` clause, but Access can apparently run that strange code on native tables.  The correct code that will result in the desired behavior regardless of linked or native table is thus:

```
SELECT linked.ASSIGNED_CARE_COORDINATOR, [rest of the variables]
FROM linked
WHERE ((linked.ASSIGNED_CARE_COORDINATOR)=[Forms]![frmCoord_Selector]![cmbCoords])
     OR [Forms]![frmCoord_Selector]![cmbCoords] Is Null
```

Comment: *Access apparently added the 'LIKE' unnecessarily*...how did MS Access add it? You as the designer update forms including recordsources.

Comment: @Parfait Hmm, going back and reviewing the design view of the query it appears that the code with the 'LIKE' was typed in to the 'Field' field manually.  It's been long enough since I designed the original using the native tables that I don't remember either way.  I'm going to edit my answer to remove that part.